# Dojo TimeTextBox validate on increments

Tags: validation, dojo

I see lots of pages with the exact same documentation on TimeTextBox dijits, like this:

```
require(["dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TimeTextBox){
    new TimeTextBox({name: "progval", value: new Date(),
        constraints: {
            timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
            clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
            visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
            visibleRange: 'T01:00:00'
        }
    }, "progval");
});
```

I really wish the Dojo foundation would provide actual documentation instead of a couple simple examples.

The above code sets the time increments are displayed in the dropdown to 15 minutes, however it accepts any well-formatted value when you type it in.

What I want is for it to validate the increments. So if I type 00:16:00 at a 15 minute increment, it will give me an error. What constraints do I need to add? I can't even find a list of constraints anywhere.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TimeTextBox.html

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear. I WANT it to give an error if the typed in value is not a 15 minute increment. As in a Dojo will generate a tooltip that says the value is invalid and put an exclamation mark on that field like it does when you type an incorrectly formatted value.